# ErrorException Undefined array key in column table of CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having difficulty getting the blood type description to be displayed in my patients table due to receiving the blood type foreign key in Codeigniter 4.

The error happen in `<td><?php echo $p['bt']['description']; ?></td>` showing
`ErrorException Undefined array key "bt"`

- `PacientModel.php`

```
class PacientModel extends Model
{
    ...
    public function bt()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BloodTypeModel::class, 'blood_type_id');
    }
}
```

- `BloodTypeModel.php`

```
class BloodTypeModel extends Model
{
    ...
    public function blood_type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PacientModel::class, 'blood_type_id');
    }
}
```

- `PacientController.php`

```
    public function index()
    {
        $model = new PacientModel();
        $blood_type = new BloodTypeModel();

        $blood_types = $blood_type->findAll();
        $blood_types = array_column($blood_types, null, 'id');

        $pacients = [
            'pacients' => $model->paginate(10),
            'pager' => $model->pager,
            'blood_types' => $blood_types, 
        ];
        return view('pacient/index', $pacients);
    }
```

- `index.php`

```
  <?php foreach($pacients as $p): ?>
   <tr> 
     <td><?php echo $p['bt']['description']; ?> </td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `CodeIgniter 4` does not support eager loading out of the box, you need to manually join the tables or map the relationships in your controller before passing the data to the view.    PacientController.php >>

```
public function index()
{
    $model = new PacientModel();
    $pacients = $model->select('pacients.*, blood_types.description as bt_description')
                      ->join('blood_types', 'pacients.blood_type_id = blood_types.id', 'left')
                      ->paginate(10);

    $data = [
        'pacients' => $pacients,
        'pager' => $model->pager
    ];

    return view('pacient/index', $data);
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php foreach($pacients as $p): ?>
<tr> 
  <td><?php echo $p['bt_description']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Typically, building and executing a query is the responsibility of a model and should not be found in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($pacients['pacients'] as $p): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $p->bt->description; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Additionally, you might want to eager load the blood type relationship to avoid the N+1 query problem. In your controller, you can modify the query like this

```
$pacients = [
    'pacients' => $model->with('bt')->paginate(10),
    'pager' => $model->pager,
];
```

This will load the blood type relationship for all the patients in a single query.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to take some time to familiarise yourself with the site rules, including the one that [bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) so-called "AI" generated content.